# New to Python and Web-scraping. Scraping an HTML table- however it's not displaying all columns

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup and trying to scrap a HTML table. I'm only interested in the first table. However, the output is missing one column values - the "Entries" column. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

for child in soup.find_all('table')[0].children:
    for td in child:
        print(td.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way how to read the first table is using `pandas.read_html`:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.godaycare.com/child-care-cost/saskatchewan"

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | Type | Age Cat. | Spot | AVG. Cost ($) | Entries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Licensed | Infant | Full-Time | 751.02 | 717 |
| 1 | Licensed | Infant | Part-Time | 41.31 | 187 |
| 2 | Unlicensed | Infant | Full-Time | 699.56 | 287 |
| 3 | Unlicensed | Infant | Part-Time | 31.05 | 50 |
| 4 | Licensed | Toddler | Full-Time | 661.04 | 604 |
| 5 | Licensed | Toddler | Part-Time | 32.69 | 148 |
| 6 | Unlicensed | Toddler | Full-Time | 633.01 | 342 |
| 7 | Unlicensed | Toddler | Part-Time | 35.99 | 69 |
| 8 | Licensed | Preschool | Full-Time | 595.45 | 327 |
| 9 | Licensed | Preschool | Part-Time | 30.85 | 66 |
| 10 | Unlicensed | Preschool | Full-Time | 602.82 | 195 |
| 11 | Unlicensed | Preschool | Part-Time | 30.33 | 30 |
| 12 | Licensed | Kindergarten | Full-Time | 562.87 | 87 |
| 13 | Licensed | Kindergarten | Part-Time | 28.29 | 38 |
| 14 | Unlicensed | Kindergarten | Full-Time | 549.12 | 57 |
| 15 | Unlicensed | Kindergarten | Part-Time | 23.01 | 13 |
| 16 | Licensed | Schoolage | Full-Time | 605.34 | 94 |
| 17 | Licensed | Schoolage | Part-Time | 25.45 | 33 |
| 18 | Unlicensed | Schoolage | Full-Time | 434.9 | 98 |
| 19 | Unlicensed | Schoolage | Part-Time | 19 | 25 |

---

EDIT: Version with `beautifulsoup`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.godaycare.com/child-care-cost/saskatchewan"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for row in soup.find("table").find_all("tr"):
    tds = [td.text for td in row.find_all(["td", "th"])]
    print(("{:<20}" * len(tds)).format(*tds))
```

Prints:

```
Type                Age Cat.            Spot                AVG. Cost ($)       Entries             
Licensed            Infant              Full-Time           751.02              717                 
Licensed            Infant              Part-Time           41.31               187                 
Unlicensed          Infant              Full-Time           699.56              287                 
Unlicensed          Infant              Part-Time           31.05               50                  
Licensed            Toddler             Full-Time           661.04              604                 
Licensed            Toddler             Part-Time           32.69               148                 
Unlicensed          Toddler             Full-Time           633.01              342                 
Unlicensed          Toddler             Part-Time           35.99               69                  
Licensed            Preschool           Full-Time           595.45              327                 
Licensed            Preschool           Part-Time           30.85               66                  
Unlicensed          Preschool           Full-Time           602.82              195                 
Unlicensed          Preschool           Part-Time           30.33               30                  
Licensed            Kindergarten        Full-Time           562.87              87                  
Licensed            Kindergarten        Part-Time           28.29               38                  
Unlicensed          Kindergarten        Full-Time           549.12              57                  
Unlicensed          Kindergarten        Part-Time           23.01               13                  
Licensed            Schoolage           Full-Time           605.34              94                  
Licensed            Schoolage           Part-Time           25.45               33                  
Unlicensed          Schoolage           Full-Time           434.90              98                  
Unlicensed          Schoolage           Part-Time           19.00               25
```

Comment: Thank you. I was also trying to learn beautiful soup for my self-learning. Would you have an idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: @Ventorro I've edited my answer. To use `beautifulsoup`, first select the first `<table>` and then itereate over rows (`<tr>`). In each row, grab all `<td>` or `<th>` and print them.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. :)

Sorry, I have a dumb question. If we have more rows in the future i.e if website adds more data then this won't work?

Comment: @Ventorro This solution will work with any number of rows in the table (as long as formatting of the page won't change).

Comment: @Ventorro No, this is just string formatting, you can use `print(*tds)` but the output won't be so pretty.